# JavaScript Arrays inside an .each() loop not adding new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, validation

I'm testing some form validation using the HTML5 'pattern' attribute and corresponding JS. Full disclosure, I'm stuck using IE 11 if that makes any difference.

So far, I've been able to get my script to loop over and pull the patterns from HTML inputs and convert them into a RegExp for the .test() method. The validation portion seems to be working.

I would like to store the form inputs into an array, e.g.: **formData[fieldData, fieldData, fieldData]**

...and store their validation states into another array, e.g.: **validationStates[true, false, true]**

...and then enable the SUBMIT button once .every() **validationState** is **true** (not in the code yet).

My problem is that my array(s) are only ever 1 element long - new values are not being .push()ed to them. The console is consistently reporting that each array is .length 1, as if it's being overwritten during each pass of the loop (I've also tried a non-destructive .splice() as you can see). What am I doing wrong?

```js
$("input").change(function() {
  console.clear();
  $("[required]").each(function(index) {         // find all required form fields
    var fieldData, regex;                          // init variables
    var formData = [];                             // init array for form input data
    var validationStates = [];                     // init array for validation states
    
    fieldData = $(this).val();                     // get form values and store
    regex = new RegExp($(this).attr("pattern"));   // pull regex from pattern(s)
    formData.splice(index, 0, fieldData);          // store the field inputs in an array
    validationStates.push((regex.test(fieldData)));
    
    console.log(formData);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(validationStates);
  });
});
```

```css
.form-control, .btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input:invalid, textarea:invalid {
  border: 1px dotted #F33 !important;
  color: #E33 !important;
}

input:valid, textarea:valid {
  border: 1px dotted #2C8 !important;
  color: #2C8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="validated_form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" pattern="^[^\s][a-zA-Z\s-.]*$" placeholder="name" required="" title="only letters and &#39;-&#39;" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="time" pattern="^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]" placeholder="time (HH:mm)" required="" title="24H time in HH:mm or H:mm format" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input class="form-control" id="pattern" pattern="^[^&lt;&gt;\s].{5,}$" placeholder="HTML5 pattern matching test (a-z only, more than 5 characters)" required="" title="must be more than 5 characters" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-info disabled" disabled="true" id="sub" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">Submit Form</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your arrays before the .change() and .each() loop...
and better to use let instead of var inside the loop

Explanatory edit:
what you're doing is every iteration of the each loop you're declaring a new array.. so it only ever contains one element

Edit:
Well now that i re-read... it's quite pointless to use an array to store your validation states... simply do something like:

```
change() {
    let errors = false;
    each() {
        errors = !Regexp.isItValid(input)
    }
    if(!errors)
        proceed()
}
```

pseudo code but you got what i mean

I know memory is cheap nowadays but you still shouldn't waste it for no reasons...

Comment: Actually, it should be above the .change method or else it will overwritten every time the input changes.

Comment: which is excatly what he wants EDIT: ok no you're right... didn't read full code... editing answer

Comment: Thank you both! I moved both array declarations above the $("input").change() and that took care of it - now I just need to work on the button enabling portion.

Comment: @LaurentSchwitter Re: your latest edit: I just tried things again with the error flag and it works! You're right; it is a cleaner solution. Thank you again!